# Getting data from independent child component to other components with router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm fairly new to Vue, which is why I can't ignore my feeling that I'm doing something wrong.

I have an independent component inside a view component, which has to emit data to other components.

The project has the following components: `App`, `Navbar`, `Home`, `Statistics`, `Table` and `Search`.

The `Search` component is used inside the `Home` component. It contains an `<input>` to let the user input his account name.

The `Table` component is used inside the `Statistics` component. It shows a table **based on the input from the `Search` component.**

```
+-- App
|   +-- Navbar
|   +-- Home
|   +-- ---- Search
|   +-- Statistics
|   +-- ---- Table
```

My main `App.vue` contains the `router-view`:

```
<template>
<div id="app">

  <Navbar></Navbar>

  <div class="container">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

Two of them are main view components, which have a fixed route: `Home` & `Statistics`.
The routes (`router.js`) are the following:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/statistics',
      name: 'statistics',
      component: Statistics
    }
  ]
})
```

The `Navbar` component contains the `router-link`s to the view components:

```
<template>
  <div id="navbar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/statistics">Statistics</router-link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now: What is the right way to get the data from the independent child component `Search` to my other independent child component `Table`?

The logical way would be `Search`-> `Home` -> `App` -> `Statistics` -> `Table`.

I already tried to use an event bus with `$emit` and `$on`, but it seems like the data can't connect to each other with the router inbetween.

Right now, I have a const in my `main.js` to store this global user data:

```
export const store = new Vue({
  data: {
    username: ''
  }
})
```

which I import everywhere I need it, but I highly doubt that this is the right way to do it.

I also thought about using props for my `Table` component, but I would need to pass my data from `App` to `Statistics` to `Table` which would work, but feels like a lot of boilerplate. Also: I need to get the username to the `App` before I can do that anyways, which is what I don't know how to do proberly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey are you able to make an [mcve] e.g. with http://plnkr.co, https://jsfiddle.net/, etc.?

Comment: Hey I see you have an accepted answer here... did you still need [the cross-posted question on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194470/120114)?

Comment: @AndrewElliott I created the question on CR before the answer was posted here. Why do you ask?

Comment: Just curious if the accept answer also answers the question on CR... if not, could you add more details to that post, like the markup and VueJS for all components mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to use a global store as you are doing, the docs even have a guide on how to do so: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

If you want a more structured way of doing this, look into Vuex, which is also written by the Vue team: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Vuex integrates nicely into the Vue devtools and sidesteps the import/passing problems you're describing (because it is a plugin injected via `Vue.use`, then `$store` is available in every Vue)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm afraid that vuex would add even more boilerplate, I thought there would be a much more simple way to share global data between independent components.

Comment: @BennettDams if not using Vuex, then I would just export the store as its own module. That way, other modules aren't importing it from App, they are just importing the independent Store module. It is basically a Singleton pattern at that point

Comment: When you talk about "modules", do you mean Vue components or Vuex modules?

Comment: @BennettDams Vue components (as JS modules). I would make a `Store` at the root (peer with App). That way any component downstream can just `import Store from '@/store'`